# Boot a legacy BIOS OS on a GPT mass memory?

Tags: boot, uefi, mbr

I installed Windows 95 (legacy BIOS OS) with DOSBox on a 64 bit PC, on a FAT32 partition (with (I hope) its PBR (partition boot record)) on a GPT hard disk, with UEFI Windows 11 and the ESP (EFI system partition).

I can't boot it with legacy BIOS CSM (that I set in BIOS Setup Utility, pressing <kbd>del</kbd> at start) neither VirtualBox.

On Windows 11, I can't activate the partition:

```
diskpart
sel disk 0
sel part 8  // the Windows 95 FAT32 partition
active

The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk.  
The ACTIVE command can only be used on fixed MBR disks.
```

So the hard disk need a MBR but according to https://www.diskpart.com/gpt-mbr/mbr-and-gpt-on-same-disk-7201.html it's not possible to have GPT and MBR on the same mass memory.

So what to do?
Maybe an .efi file in the ESP which can boot a legacy BIOS OS, PBR partition, no need MBR?
With GRUB?

Comment: Windows 95 cannot work on a UEFI based computer. You are better off installing it in a Virtual Machine that can emulate a BIOS based system for it.

Comment: Windows 95 a 16-bit OS cannot be booted on a device that comes with Windows 11. The physical processor does not support the OS.

Comment: @Ramhound x86_64 CPUs are still completely backwards-compatible AFAIK. It's a limitation of 64-bit Windows that it doesn't support 16-bit programs anymore + a limitation of old Windowses that they won't run on modern hardware (although IIRC there's a 2.0 GHz+ patch for Win95, not sure how it will handle multiple cores though and you certainly won't find any drivers)

Comment: Yes, the main limitation is that the CPU can't run 16-bit code while in 64-bit "long mode" – but it _could_ still run 16-bit code if the OS is running in 32-bit mode. (Also, Windows 95 isn't 16-bit – it's _mostly_ 32-bit, with some 16-bit leftovers here and there.) But... I wouldn't be surprised if modern CPUs didn't have an actual 16-bit "real mode" anymore, which Win95 probably requires at least during the initial boot process?

Comment: @gronostaj - Most Windows 11 devices don’t even support a Legacy Mode, and if they do, they are using a 64-bit UEFI kernel. Your comment confuses me as it confirms the processor probably won’t support Windows 95. Only way to run a 16-bit oS on modern equipment is a vm

Comment: Put Windows 95 in a Virtual Machine. I do that and it works fine.

Comment: there must not be any spaces between normal punctuations, except parentheses and quotes which must not have spaces inside. That's the basic [punctuation rule](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/spacing.asp)

Comment: and why on earth do you install Windows 95 alongside a modern OS in a modern PC? Even most BIOS mainboards lost the ability to boot Windows 98 more than a decade ago, that's explicitly said in their manuals. Windows 9x requires some drivers that no one maintains and ported anymore so they can only run in legacy hardware or in a virtual machine. This is off-topic here and should be on [retrocomputing.se] instead

Answer (score 6):

It *is* actually possible to have MBR boot code on GPT-partitioned disks – the 0th sector remains reserved specifically to hold a "protective MBR" which can still hold BIOS boot code like before (as long as you boot it in legacy mode, as UEFI won't even look at the MBR boot code even if it's there).

(For that matter, UEFI doesn't actually require GPT to be used – MBR-partitioned disks are still part of the UEFI specification. The boot code part of the MBR still remains unused by UEFI and so can hold legacy BIOS boot code if needed.)

You can install the [Syslinux](https://wiki.syslinux.org/) MBR boot code (gptmbr.bin), which behaves very much like traditional MBRs that jump to an active partition's PBR, but understands GPT partition tables and looks for a similarly named GPT attribute flag. (Specifically, it checks bit 2 which `gdisk` calls "Legacy BIOS bootable.") The rest of Syslinux is not needed.

But you must use legacy boot mode (CSM) for this to work at all. Both the MBR **and** the PBR hold boot code written specifically for BIOS boot (neither of them is used in UEFI boot process); often they rely on accessing the disk through BIOS calls (interrupts), which naturally will be unavailable if you're trying to run that code in an UEFI environment with no CSM.

So it's not enough to just have an .efi executable that tries to run a MBR or PBR – you need to use legacy mode, or if you don't have it you would need to bring in a *whole* BIOS implementation, such as perhaps SeaBIOS (which is sometimes used as the CSM within UEFI firmwares and could *probably* be started as a normal .efi binary?).

However, if the machine is so new that it no longer has UEFI CSM support for booting BIOS-style, then you will have more problems than just the initial boot – it's likely that you will have literally no Windows 9x compatible drivers for any hardware on that machine. (See the sidebar of [/r/windows98](https://old.reddit.com/r/windows98/) for more details – anything that "came with Windows 7" is already too-new, so your machine will be *extremely* too-new.)